# I don't understand the Image class! What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, image

quite a newbie here but here's a small test code that explains my issue. The value printed is -1. I just don't have the slightest clue on how to return the pixel width of my image, am I missing something very obvious here? This whole ImageObserver thingy makes no sense!!!

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;



    class imagetest2 extends JPanel {
        Image i =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(/*image*/);

        public int test(){
            int x = i.getWidth(null);
            return x;
        }


    }

    class imagetest {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            imagetest2 tesst = new imagetest2();
            System.out.print(tesst.test());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage()` might asynchronously load the image which is almost never what you want.

Use `ImageIO` and a `BufferedImage` instead which also has `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` without an `ImageObserver` parameter (although the other ones will work as well if you pass `null`):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read("/*image*/");
int width = image.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just using the wrong classes. There is an easier way to achieve what you want, this will do it:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class ImageTest 
{
    BufferedImage img;

    public static int getWidthFromImage(String filename)
    {
        BufferedImage image;
        int width;
        try
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
            return image.getWidth();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Something terrible happened! " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.print("The width of the image in pixels is: " + getWidthFromImage(args[0]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, both answers are great! By the way this forum is so messy, first time here and it's so cluttered! I'd rep you guys but apparently I can't "vote up" yet! I had been looking at the bufferedimage class but the API made it felt so scary but the imageIO really made things easier